# Why the CA function in FactorMineR tells me that undefined columns are selected?

Tags: r, factominer

I'm using a dataframe named *DataUniv* composed of 13 variables. When I try to run a correspondance analysis using FactoMineR :

```
dataUniv.CA = CA(dataUniv[,2:7],
             col.sup=c(1,8:13))
```

It sends me back this error :

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Xtot, , col.sup) : undefined columns selected
```

I don't really understand why it sent me back this type of error, as it seems that those columns are effectively defined, if I run :

```
View(dataUniv[,2:7])
View(dataUniv[,c(1,8:13)])
```

It returns something good...

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data in order to make the error reproducible.

Comment: I finally found it : col.sup argument must contain columns that are included in the first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it: the `col.sup` argument must contain columns that are included in the first argument.